# React Native borderRadius one corner not round

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello this is the code I'm using:

```
  menuItemButtonContainer: {
    marginRight: 1,
    marginLeft: 1,
    marginTop: 1,
    marginBottom: 1,
    paddingRight: 1,
    paddingLeft: 1,
    paddingTop: 1,
    paddingBottom: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: colors.navy
  },
```

but for some reason the top right corner is not round. I've been cudgeling my brain for a day.

This is the component code

```
<Native.View
          style={[styles.menuItemButtonContainer, {width: 50, height: 30, marginLeft: 0}]}><Native.TouchableHighlight
          underlayColor={colors.darkGray}
          onPress={this.orderObjectChange.bind(this, 'ADD', item.id)}
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}><Native.View><Components.Text
          style={{color: colors.navy}}>ADD</Components.Text></Native.View></Native.TouchableHighlight></Native.View>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide code for the component as well?

Comment: Can you inspect the element and see what css is applied to it? That should give you the answer. Also, look for other places in your app where you define `borderRadius` and see if that interferes somehow with your element.

Comment: Component attached

Answer (score 1):

Styles you written works, Please see the below. May be border style getting overridden by some other styles in your application.Inspect that element to see.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the border radius on each corner as follows:

```
 menuItemButtonContainer: {
    marginRight: 1,
    marginLeft: 1,
    marginTop: 1,
    marginBottom: 1,
    paddingRight: 1,
    paddingLeft: 1,
    paddingTop: 1,
    paddingBottom: 1,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10, //Top Left Corner
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,// Top Right Corner
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,// Bottom Left Corner
    borderBottomRightRadius: 10, // Bottom Right Corner
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: colors.navy
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

As I have reviewed your code and as per that, you try by using below property to give corner radius one bye one for all the corner

```
borderBottomLeftRadius: 10
borderBottomRightRadius: 10
borderTopLeftRadius: 10
borderTopRightRadius: 10
```

Answer (score -1):

You may also use the sx prop like this:

```
sx={{"& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
          borderRadius: '0 10px 0 0'
          }}}
```